# How to transfer jpg image using UDP socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I want to transfer an jpg image via an UDP connection. I want a java code to convert the image into a byte array and to recreate the jpg file on the other side.

Code I tried

Image To ByteArray

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/test.jpg"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
    baos.flush();
    byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int c=0;

    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();       
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.1");
    System.out.println(buffer.length);
    for(int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++){
        buff[c] = buffer[i];
        c++;
        if(i%1023==0){
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, IPAddress, 9876);
            buff = new byte[1024];
            c=0;
            clientSocket.send(packet);

            System.out.println("sent a mini-packet");
        }
    }
```

ByteArray To image

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recv_message);
try {
  DatagramSocket clientsocket=new DatagramSocket(9876);
  byte[] receivedata = new byte[1024];
  while(true)
  {
    DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(receivedata, receivedata.length);
    Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");

    clientsocket.receive(recv_packet);       

    byte[] buff = recv_packet.getData();
    final Bitmap new_img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buff, 0,
            buff.length);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("received");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
            image.setImageBitmap(new_img);
        }
    });



    InetAddress ipaddress = recv_packet.getAddress();
    int port = recv_packet.getPort();
    Log.d("IPAddress : ",ipaddress.toString());
    Log.d(" Port : ",Integer.toString(port));
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("UDP", "S: Error", e);
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          tv.setText("Error Occured");
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Show some code you have tried so far

Comment: Your sending part seems to be correct. I guess the problem is because of incomplete receiving of bytes as the datagram packets may get lost. Please do specify the problem you are getting. Also ensure whether your devices are able to communicate through udp or not i.e, any packet is received or not.

Comment: @KunjanThadani Communication works fine. I have tested it by transferring a text. But when it comes to a image, it doesn't working. I also think the problem is in the receiving part. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a slight problem in the way the image is sent.
Initially the image is converted into byte[] and then the individual bytes are sent i.e, the complete image is broken and sent through different smaller packets.

Now, when you try to receive the packets each of these packet is received individually and an image is being created everytime a small packet is received.

For ex. let image be of 1024 bytes. You are sending its individual bytes like 1, then 2, ..... 1024.
While receiving them, say packet 1 is received, it is creating an image with that single packet.
Similarly, when 2nd packet arrives, another image is being created.

But an image is to be created with complete 1024 bytes.
That is why, you are not getting the result you want.

You need to implement a mechanism to buffer them into a single byte[] & then form an image.

For now, just do one thing. Send the image in a single unit i.e, create a byte[] from the image & send it directly without breaking it or sending the bytes individually from loop.

```
 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/test.jpg"));
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
 ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
 baos.flush();
 byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();

 DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();       
 InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.1");
 System.out.println(buffer.length);

  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, IPAddress, 9876);

  clientSocket.send(packet);
```

Now, when you receive the packet, a complete image can be formed as all 1024 bytes will be received at once.

Comment: yeah sure, but I don't have the permission to vote since I am new to stack-overflow. I am very sorry about that.

Comment: Oh yes, i didnt notice that. Fine no problem.

Comment: What if the image is bigger than 65535 bytes?